# Declaring a variable without specifying its data type in C++

Tags: c++, variables

Why is it necessary  to specify the datatype of a variable? What if my program requires the user to enter data that could belong to any one of two non intersecting data types? Shouldn't the option of declaring a variable without specifying a variable be provided so as to account for a situation. Why can't we let the computer decide the data type on the basis of user input? If the compiler has enough capability to identify a type error, I'm sure it can easily specify a data type on the basis of the input.

Comment: You are questioning the fundamental definition of a strongly typed language. Knowing the type of every variable and every expression at compile time makes C and C++ strongly typed languages. Without that, you will have a weakly typed language, such as PERL, JavaScript, PHP.

Comment: Because that isn't how C++ is designed. It leaves this part of the program to the application programmer, not the language. If you want a language with more flexible data typing, use a dynamic language like PHP or Lisp.

Comment: I thought that I'll just add that I'm quite new to programming and C++. This question came up while reading a chapter on data handling and after internet searches proved futile (most of the answers were about C) I decided to post this question.

@RSahu So that's what it's all about! That settles my question. I think I will be able to fully grasp why C++ doesn't provide this option by reading about strongly typed and weakly typed languages. Thanks!

Comment: For the situation of reading any one of a number of types, you create your own type (or reuse somebody else's) that represents "any one of these". Even in other languages, you usually need to indicate how you want input to be interpreted (e.g. whether `123` should be treated as an integer or a string or three characters).

Comment: How could the application know what the data type is supposed to be? If I typed in "3" is that a number or a string?  Is 129.169.1.1 a number, string or IP address? Is "Blue" a string or a colour?  The user will always enter a string. It's up to your program logic to determine which type it can be converted to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilers don't deal with input, so that's no option.

There's `boost::variant<T,U>` which is a type can hold either `T` or `U` values, but you still have to specify to the compiler all possible options, and you have to make clear what you put in.

User input always starts out as a string. Parsing turns that into types, but the result depends on the actual parsing. If you're parsing float values, `0` is a perfectly fine float value.